# copy from xls document into word using vba

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word, office-2007

I'm trying to make a code in which to copy charts from a xls file into a word document using the PasteSpecial property (picture(enhanced metafile). I would like to change the existing charts of the document to new ones. So, I thought that using bookmarks for the existing charts would be OK. I'm using OFFICE 2007.

I've written the following code:

```
        Dim YMApp As Word.Application
        Dim YMDoc As Word.Document
        Dim B as Bookmark
        paaath = "D:\"
        dime = "NameOld.doc"
        dime2 = "NameNew.doc"
        Set YMApp = New Word.Application
        YMApp.Visible = True
        Set YMDoc = YMApp.Documents.Open(paaath & dime)
        Word.Documents(dime).SaveAs (paaath + dime2)
        For k = 1 To 6
            Windows("New.xls").Activate
            Sheets("graph").Select
            Range("L" + Trim(Str(br(k))) + ":V" + Trim(Str(br(k) + 24))).Select
            Selection.Copy
            ddd = "bm" + Trim(Str(k))
            Set B = YMDoc.Bookmarks(ddd)
            YMApp.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=B
        Next k
        YMDoc.Close
        YMApp.Quit
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        ActiveWorkbook.Close
    End
End Sub
```

The problem is that by this code the bookmarks which are already created are not recognized. How to cope with the problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "the bookmarks are not recognized"?  DO you get an error? Or does the output just not match your expectations?  Please elaborate...

Comment: Sorry, for the incorrect statement. I'm not a specialist. This is like a hobby and I'm trying to reduce the time for implementation of my job. I'm not getting an error, simply the charts are not placed where the bookmarks are, but in the beginning of the sheet one over another.

Answer (score 0):

The `Placement` argument of [`PasteSpecial`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff191763.aspx) does not accept a `Bookmark` object:

```
Set B = YMDoc.Bookmarks(ddd)
YMApp.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=B
```

Instead, it takes a [`WdOLEPlacement` constant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838530.aspx).

I think you'll need to select the bookmark before you do the `PasteSpecial`. You may need to delete existing chart (if any), also.

Untested, but I think you need something like this:

```
Dim wdRange as Word.Range
Set B = YMDoc.Bookmarks(ddd)
Set wdRange = B.Range

YMApp.Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookMark, Name:=B.Name

' Delete existing shapes & bookmark if any:
On Error Resume Next
YMDoc.ShapeRange(1).Delete
wdRange.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
YMApp.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=0 'Or 1

'Add the bookmark back in place:
MDoc.Selection.Bookmarks.Add Name:=ddd, wdRange
```

Comment: thank you for this suggestion: may be you are right - placement argument does not accept a bookmark object. After I debug the code it gave me error at the last statement saying that the first bookmark is no longer available. and the chart was in the beginning of the word document. As I said I'm not a specialist (I have some experience with VBA but not enough in this "word objects, bookmarks" and so on. Could you suggest something else, please.

Comment: You're right, the existing `B` bookmark got deleted, change the last line to:  `YMDoc.Bookmarks.Add ddd, wdRange`

Comment: Everything looks "fine" only the placement is not where I would like to be. By this code the placement of the chart is where the cursor is in the beginning (before selecting the bookmark). I tried  YMDoc.ShapeRange(1).Delete

On Error GoTo 0
YMApp.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=0 'Or 1

Comment: Everything looks "fine" only the placement is not where I would like to be. By this code the placement of the chart is where the cursor is in the beginning (before selecting the bookmark). I tried your proposal but modified it a little:

YMDoc.ShapeRange(1).Delete
On Error GoTo 0
YMApp.Selection.PasteSpecial DataType:=wdPasteMetafilePicture, Placement:=wdRange 'Or 1
But got an error: 4198 
"Command failed"

Comment: I succeeded with inputting of chart in word. The only thing which remains is how to input bookmark over the respective chart? using the `YMDoc.Bookmarks.Add Name:=ddd` it places it right  after the chart but I would like the bookmark to be over the chart in order next time I need it to be able to replace easily the chart. Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmmmm @Georgy looking back on some of my old code, I think that the Bookmark can't be "over" the chart itself, the bookmark is only a positional part of the Document text.  I believe that what I did in the past to circumvent this, was to ensure that the charts were named consistently with the bookmarks, i.e., I would have a bookmark called "Chart1" and at that location I would insert the chart named "Chart1", etc.  (You can use other properties of the chart for this, actually it would be preferable to use the `.AlternativeText` or maybe a `CustomXMLPart` to do this mapping)

Comment: I'm sure that the bookmarks could be over a chart (this is what I did manually in the beginning). And the first time I execute the macro the charts are replaced with the new ones. After that the problem is that I do not know how to put the bookmarks over the new charts using code.

Comment: OK @Georgy let me revisit my earlier code, I think you may be correct :)

Comment: I've double-checked and I can't see a way to create a bookmark that anchors to an embedded object. The bookmark refers to a word `Range` object, which is just a position within the document. Now, you can select the chart and insert a bookmark there, but it's still just referring to the underlying position within the document.  Try: `YMDoc.Selection.Bookmarks.Add Name:=ddd, wdRange` and see if that gets you any better result.